# Icon set in Webkit or css3

Tags: css, webkit, icons

Is there a set of icons in web-kit or css3, I have looked over the following code:

http://codepen.io/davilious/pen/cIajf

and can not figure out where the actual icons are coming from.

Can anyone explain where the icons are being generated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [icon font](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/) from [Pictonic](https://pictonic.co/). The external stylesheet (see the CSS settings-area-thing) is `http://www.davilious.com/icons-2/css/pictonic.css`.

You can kind of make a guess from the shadow, though; that's really only possible using `text-shadow` right now.